# Karate Api Testing - How to pass data from one feature file to another

Tags: api, testing, automation, karate

I need to pass data from one feature file to another.

Feature(1): Create a new user

Background:

```
* url 'http://127.0.0.1:8900/'
* header Accept = 'application/json'
Scenario: Create a new user
 Given path '/user'
 And request {"email" : "test@test.com", "name" : "Brian"}
 When method post
 And def newUser = $..id
 Then status 201
```

Feature(2): Call newUser from feature 1

Background:

```
* url 'http://127.0.0.1:8900/'
* header Accept = 'application/json'
 Scenario: Call User
  * def newUser = $..id
  * print newUser
```

Answer (score 2):

Please read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-other-feature-files

```
    * def aVariable = "can be anything"
    * def result = call read('one.feature') { some: 'data', useExpression: #(aVariable) }
```

And in `one.feature` you can get access to the JSON "argument"

```
* print some
```

Which should print the value `data`

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the response. I've tried the above and as a result of calling one.feature I end up with 2 new users. I would like one.feature to POST a new user and pass the response to two.feature where I can verify the user was created.

Comment: @MarkHughes sorry I can't understand - maybe someone else has a better answer for you, all the best. I really think you haven't understood the docs and examples if you have already gone through them

Comment: I'm simply trying to pass data from feature to another .... maybe I don't understand your documentation but that response should be your answer for everything.

Comment: @MarkHughes see my edit. and read the docs. I have nothing more to add. all the very best

Comment: @MarkHughes The callfeature demo at the following link should be helpful: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/callfeature

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it 