# How to loop over array values in a karate feature

Tags: loops, automation, bdd, karate

I am trying to loop over array values in a karate feature file.
In a Feature1.feature - Scenario1, I have some values in the array ["UUID1","UUID2","UUID3"] and I want to call another feature file (Feature2.feature) (having a code to call a DELETE endpoint) of a service

Feature2.feature:

```
 @ignore

Feature: Delete

  Background:

    * url baseUrl
    * headers {content-type:'application/json'}

  Scenario: Delete Test Assets

    Given headers {uid: '#(UId)', cid:'#(CId)'}
    And path 'type', Type, 'id', AssetId
    When method delete
    Then status 204
```

What approach should I use to Feature1.feature to call the Feature2.feature in a loop?

Comment: Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59200648/442595

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an array of primitives, you need to convert it into an array of JSON objects before doing a "loop call". Refer to the docs for `karate.mapWithKey()`: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms

So do this:

```
* def data =  ["UUID1","UUID2","UUID3"]
* def data = karate.mapWithKey(data, 'uid')
* call read('second.feature') data
```

And in `second.feature`:

```
* headers { uid: '#(uid)' }
```

Of course, read the docs for `call` if needed: https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features

Comment: This worked like a charm. That was actually what I wanted to do.Thanks @peter-thomas